# Import subfolders gives error no module named

Tags: python, import

Iam using python 3.7. I try to import its2D_1.py file. While I am importing the subfolders it gives an error 'No module names'.

The subfolder has an **init**.py and I am at the right directory

```
In [26]: from __future__ import absolute_import
In [27]: from .examples.linear_elasticity.its2D_1 import *
ModuleNotFoundError     
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'examples.linear_elasticity'
```

The directory is script and the order of the folders script>examples>linear_elasticity>its2D_1.py

How could I import the linear_elasticity subfolder, thanks?

Comment: Add more details. Which Python version? What's your directory structure? Where is the file you are executing?

Comment: I am using python 3.7 and the folder structure script>examples>linear_elasticity>its2D_1.py. I am following the sfepy tutorial that I downloaded the folders when I am installing the sfepy: http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/primer.html#meshing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using python2 you need **init**.py.
From python 3.4 it has been deprecated, you don't need an **init**.py file to specify if it's a package or not.

```
parent/
    __init__.py
    one/
        __init__.py
    two/
        __init__.py
    three/
        __init__.py
```

Importing parent.one will implicitly execute parent/**init**.py and parent/one/**init**.py. 
https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html
From this link:
foo.bar.baz. In this case, Python first tries to import foo, then foo.bar, and finally foo.bar.baz. If any of the intermediate imports fail, a ModuleNotFoundError is raised.

Comment: Thanks for your comment but it is not working, I believe it is the problem that I downloaded from sfepy tutorial. Somehow it does not see the subfolder, do you have any other suggestion to import subfolder? I am using python 3.7 ann the tuorial link:http://sfepy.org/doc-devel/primer.html#meshing

Comment: Yes I looked at the documentation and I found 2 things.First was that they wrote "from examples.linear_elasticity.its2D_1 import *" not "from .examples.linear_elasticity.its2D_1 import *" , the extra '.' in front of examples. Second was that you could try to run its2D_1.py by running simple.py script.